# Qt5 transparent window appears black

Tags: qt, transparent

I have a transparent application window in Qt. This windows contains elements such as rectangles and buttons. I use Qt5 on Windows 8 with MinGw 5.7. Everything works fine on Windows 8 and 10: the elements appear on the transparent window. However, when I try my program on Windows 7, instead of being transparent, the application window appears black.

Here is a simple code to reproduce the problem:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    color:"transparent"

    Rectangle
    {
        width: 150
        height: 150
        color:"red"
    }
}
```

Thank you very much,

Alex